# How to use libgdx progress bar when loading a skin via asset manager

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

Given that the scene2d progress bar uses a skin, there is a circular reference there. How does one skin a progress bar that tracks the loading of an asset manager that's loading the same skin?

- Breaking it out into two skins seems overkill, but would work
- Maybe skins are not meant to be large enough to warrant progress bars, So just load the skin without the bar, and use the bar to track the loading of other non-skin assets?
- Is there some other feature of libgdx that allows me to track when specific parts of a skin are loading?

Comment: 1) Depends if your complete skin is small enough to justify delaying the loading screen until it is loaded. 2) not quite sure what your suggesting.  3) nope. If your skin is relatively small, add the skin to the asset manager and wait for it to finish loading, then start the progress bar and load the rest. If your skin is so big it’s taking too long to start showing the loading screen, then do two skins.

Comment: @Tenfour04 My #2 basically just meant - keep the skin small, and load everything else after the skin is loaded (either in a second skin or manually). Which sort of lines up with your suggestion. So that's the direction I'll head in.